# WebView Troubleshooting

Tags: android-studio, webview

I tried making an app that converts a website into a android studio app. The website I tried to convert have 2 parts to it: a "blog" and a ecommerce shop. To access the shop you NEED to log in, you can't access it otherwise. When trying to log in from the emulators google browser it works, but not from the app. I tried converting amazon to app and it works. What can I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rGrK.png)

this is the code

```
package com.ca.prosol.ui.gallery;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.ca.prosol.databinding.FragmentGalleryBinding;

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentGalleryBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();


        final WebView contributeWebView = binding.idWebViewContribute;
        final ProgressBar loadingPB = binding.idPBLoading;

        WebSettings webSettings = contributeWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        contributeWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        contributeWebView.loadUrl("https://shop.prosol.ca/login");

        contributeWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                loadingPB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        contributeWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    switch (keyCode){
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                            if(contributeWebView.canGoBack()){
                                contributeWebView.goBack();
                            }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```